# MPLAB X IDE on computer emulation / debugging how to set input values?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, emulator

Is there any way I could emulate input into chip using the free emulator, when debugging my code to see if it responds correctly into input?

Comment: Are you talking about simulating input on the I/O ports?

Comment: You should really consult the documentation.

Comment: Can you direct me to the right part of that documentation, because I couldn't find anything related to this when I read that yesterday...

Comment: @CamilStaps yes and analog signal input too.

Comment: See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gzeR4YnMFY

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there definitely is.  A fairly elaborate system has been in MPLAB for a long time, including in version 8.  However, the full details weren't documented until recently.  Only a stripped down set of capbilities via a clickety-click GUI were available.

Comment: Can you specify how can I use that to debug my program? Haven't found it yet.

Comment: @Theam: Yes, I probably can.

Comment: Thanks can you update that into your answer please. Can't wait to try it out. :D

Comment: @Theam: Yes I could.  But, this is getting tiring.  I answer your questions, then you keep coming back with more unrelated questions.